# Tag Badges with empty stats

Tags: bug, profile-page, badge-progress

On a user's activity page in the "Summary" tab, there is a cog button to select the "next tag badge" to track.  Clicking this button brings up a list of tags with statistics for "score" and "answers".

The numbers of answers posted by the user under each tag and the votes they collect contribute to these stats.  But, the numbers of questions and *their* votes don't contribute at all.

However, every tag associated with *both* the user's answers *and* their questions are listed.
Consequently, at the bottom of the list are several badges with the rather useless 0,0 stat.

[image: list of recommended tag badges with empty stats]

Either:

1. **Questions and their votes should added to tag badge stats.**
   *or*
2. **Badges that are associated with questions only, shouldn't appear in *this* list.**

It doesn't make any sense to list tag badges that haven't got any badge progress at all (i.e. with empty stats).

---

Further down the activity page (or in the "tags" tab), tags are listed with stats for "score" and "posts". Here: "posts" includes tags associated with *both* of the user's answers *and* questions.

[image: tags summary]

It guess it makes sense to include answer and question stats *here*, but votes for questions don't seem to contribute to the score.
I don't understand why the tags statistics have been designed this way —

**If questions under a tag are going to be counted *here*, shouldn't question votes be added to the score?**

Comment: I disagree with 1) but 2) is interesting...

Comment: *It doesn't make any sense to list tag badges that haven't got any badge progress at all* .... Why not? It might be inspirational to see a tag that you might want to develop. If you asked a question about it, you might as well have some knowledge to start answering in that tag. In case it matters: it only shows a top 100 of badges. For example on my badge progress dialog it shows 100 of 214 available badges. So I don't see any 0/0 scoring tags in that list.

Comment: @rene — Personally I don't find "0% progress" particularly inspiring.  
Are you suggesting it's actually a feature, or just a bug with a silver lining?

Comment: I think it is "by design". Not sure if it was carefully designed this way to call it a feature. Definitely not a bug.

Comment: @rene — Well I'm not convinced it's either intentional or useful, but if you really think it is, then I guess you should post that as an answer.